# Resolve symbolic link to local CSS file

Tags: google-chrome, browser, symbolic-link, css

I am viewing some webpages I have generated on my local computer. I have a file called "style.css" in each directly which is symbolically linked to a global CSS file (Windows 10 - I use the MINGW command `ln -svf` to generate it). It is called by each html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Firefox browser recognizes this and applies this style but Chrome does not. Is there a setting in Chrome which enables this?

Comment: MINGW symbolic links only have meaning within the MINGW file-system. They do not apply to Windows apps such as the browser.

Comment: However Firefox on the same Windows machine seems to recognize them.

Comment: Do you start it from MINGW? And why use the ancient MINGW when WSL now exists?

Comment: Nope, just open file with Firefox in Windows Explorer works. My workflow is in Windows so MINGW makes a lot more sense. Elieveme, I wanted WSL to work. WSL2 was one of the first things I got running in my Windows machine but Xwindows was not working well esp with multiple monitors and lack of systemmd